# Amazon EC2 password prompt when "su - ec2-user"

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, amazon-ec2

I can SSH in fine with my .pem file, to be automatically logged in as ec2-user.

I can create a new user and password fine, and login with `su - testUser`.

How do I log back into ec2-user without exiting the SSH session and re-connecting with the .pem file?

I've tried `su -` and `su - ec2-user`, both of which prompt for passwords.

Entering no password gives *su: Authentication failure*.

As far as I'm aware, there is no default password.

Or is it simply intended for one to set a password for ec2-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered all I had to do was type `exit` to be logged out of *testUser*, back to *ec2-user*.

Then typing in `exit` again logs out of the SSH session.